# Frame selected with precise window fit

Tags: python

is there a opition to use the 'Frame selected' and get a precise fit of the selected object in the 3dView.
I want the same behaviour like the 'Camera Fit Frame to Selected' where the object fits exactly the camera border but only for the 3dView instead of the camera view.

```py
import bpy
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
for region in area.regions:
    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
        override = {'area': area, 'region': region, 'edit_object': bpy.context.edit_object}
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(override)
```

There is no option to zoom in to fit the selection.
Any tips are welcome.